# Is there a way to test how much latency I would get before I buy?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there some way for me to test out what kind of latency I'd get in SWTOR without actually buying the game? E.g., pinging the game server IPs? (anyone has those IPs?)

I'm asking because I currently live in China, and due to SWTOR's regional restrictions I must play via a VPN. Just a little worried that I'd dish out $60 only to find out the game is too lagged for me to play over a VPN.

Comment: Know where your coming from here, used to play WoW in China (Shanghai) and tried using a VPN (Astrill) to decrease latency, but it only increased it. Battleping worked for me but then they started charging for the service so i just dealt with around 300ms while i lived there, wasn't that bad, sometimes could get as low as 250ms

Answer (score 3):

SWTOR now has a Free to Play option, you can simply create and account and install the game.  You may want to check this out to make sure everything works fine before subscribing.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother testing your VPN connection latency to the SWTOR servers specifically (presuming you have a VPN exit point at roughly the same region as the SWTOR region you're attempting to join). Just fire up your VPN and use any bandwidth/latency test to check out the general latency you'll be getting. You can usually choose a location for your bandwidth test so you can get a range of probable latency by testing at different locations around the country you VPN into (i.e. if your VPN is US East Coast, test latency on a couple points on the East and West coasts).

It might be difficult to tell what latency is acceptable for this specific game, but I think you'll get a rough answer that will either rule the game out or lead you to investigate the actual bandwidth/latency requirements.

Answer (score 0):

SWTOR recently launched APAC servers, which should give you a much better ping.

http://www.swtor.com/info/faq/game#q400115

Comment: Unfortunately, the APAC servers are closing: [http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=6048072#edit6048072](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=6048072#edit6048072)